# MVC JavaFX Chat Application - Where should the socket code be?

Tags: sockets, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm trying to employ an MVC architecture to a simple multi threaded client-server chat program. However, on the clientside, I'm unsure where the code 'which connects to a socket' and reads messages from the server should be, in the controller of the fxml view (handles the events) or the model (stores data about the chat) or the program which launches the whole program (creates the scene and stage, loads the fxml and shows the scene and stage).

I'm trying to  clear up on my MVC understanding :P

Comment: Its place is in a separate thread. This thread should be able to communicate with the application controller.

Comment: @mr mcwolf Yeah I thought it would be in a separate thread - but where would the thread be initialized and start() ?

Comment: This depends on the application design. You can run it by pressing a "connect" button for example (from the controller) or when the application starts (in `main()` or `Application::init()`, `Application::start()`). Just remember that the thread must be stopped when you exit the application. MVC is a basic design pattern and does not describe such a situation.

Comment: Understandable, but in a chat scenario, what would be examples of what the model could be used for? By my understanding, it stores and performs calculations on data - initially I thought that could be storing data from the server like the messages that are read. What are the 'calculations' and 'data' in terms of a chat app that should be in the model?  If the model does something more, it'd be nice if you mentioned it :p

Comment: The MVC model describes the data. Calculations are usually part of business logic (and it is placed in the controller). In the case of the chat application you may have two models. In one, you describe the received messages and the other users who are online. When a message is received, it is transmitted to the controller that puts it in a model. Thus, the view will be refreshed and will show a new one

Comment: How does changing a model affect the view - the model doesn't know of the view? The view is a FXML file in this case.

Comment: The FXML file is used to generate the view. The real view is what you see on the monitor (and you can communicate with it over what returns `FXMLLoader::load()`). In the libraries of `javafx`, the models represent data that implements the `Observable` interface. Views use this interface to monitor data changes. So when you add data to a similar model, the view is updated automatically.

Comment: Do not think about MVC as a design pattern that applies only at application level. It is also applied at much lower levels - like scene, panel, control ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model (lets call it `ChatModel`) part could contain `javafx.beans.Property<ChatLine>` or a `javafx.collections.ObservableList<ChatLine>`. Then your view controller will listen to this property or list change and update the view object.
This is the MVC part. 
Then your communication layer will open the chat socket and update the `ChatModel`.

Comment: So this 'communication layer' consists of classes separate from the MVC?

Comment: yes exactly. The socket should be in a separate layer. you could have 4 layers for a simple application from top to bottom : view, control, model, communication